# Who are thought leaders in the chatbot space?

Tags: chat-bots

I'm in the process of learning as much about chatbots/CUI applications as possible and I'm trying to find more information on some of the major players in this field. By this, I mean any execs, developers, academics, designers, etc. who are doing cutting edge things. Some examples could be David Marcus (VP of messaging products at Facebook) or Adam Cheyer (VP of engineering at Viv).

Answer (score 2):

One of them is certainly [Doctor Richard Wallace](http://www.alicebot.org/bios/richardwallace.html).  Doctor Wallace was the original author of the [Artificial Intelligence Markup Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIML) spec and is Chief Science Officer at PandoraBots.